# Can't solve this Number Theory problem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

> Define $A$ as the smallest integer for which $\sqrt{10 A}$ is an integer and $\sqrt[3]{6A}$ is an integer too. Get the number of Factors of A.

I think that I don't need to find the $A$ to solve this problem, there is definitely some pattern in Number Theory that I don't know.

And Also, the expected time to solve this problem is 3 minutes.
I found this problem from an exam and it was among the easiest questions(there are 20 questions for "easy" category, each giving 2 points, this was 11th), and I expect it to have a simple solution.

Comment: If $n$ is a perfect square, what can you say about the prime factorization of $n$?

Comment: integer  is the correct spelling.

Comment: Do you mean $A \times 10$ or $A^{10}$ ?

Comment: No, I mean A×10

Comment: Suggestion: to start, just focus on one condition at a time.  For which $n$ is $\sqrt {10n}$ an integer?

Comment: Yeah, I've started from there, from that I know that the last digit of A is 0

Comment: Welcome to MSE. To avoid having your question closed, try to avoid problem statement questions. You can [edit] your question to include context such as where you got this problem as well as anything you've tried e.g. checking a few values. Such information can help us help you, so try to bring something to the table. For more information, see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/272831) and [Don't know where to begin questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17164/272831).

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Welcome, @harut9.  You said if $10n$ is a perfect square then $n$ is a multiple of $10$; what can you then say about $n/10$?

Comment: n/10 is perfect square too, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Let $n=A=2^a3^b5^cd$  where $(d,30)=1$

$$10n=2^{a+1}3^b5^{c+1}d$$

So, $a+1,b,c+1$ must be even and $d$ must be perfect square

$a+1=2e,b=2f,c+1=2g, d=h^2$

$$6n=2^{a+1}3^{b+1}5^cd=2^{2c}3^{2f+1}5^{2g-1}h^2$$

So, $3$  must divide  $2e,2f+1,2g-1(1)$ and $h^2$ must be perfect cube $\ \ \ \ (2)$

$(1)\implies3|2e\iff3|e,e=3k$(sa)

$3|(b+1),b+1=3m$(say)

$3|(2g-1)\iff g=3n+2$

$(2)\implies h$ must be perfect cube $h=r^3$

So, $a=2e-1=2(3k)-1$

$b=3m-1$

$c=2g-1=2(3n+2)-1=6n+3$

Comment: You didn't answer the question ("get the number of factors of A")

Comment: @BillDubuque, If we put $a=5,b=5,c=3,h=1$ we get the minimum $n$  right?

Comment: You should put that in the answer, not a comment (I see that you added "hint" now)

Answer (score 1):

You have to say  that $A\gt0$ because if not a trivial answer is $A=0$. Well, we have
$10A=x^2$ and $6A=y^3$ which implies the diophantine equation $$10y^3=6x^2$$ Among the solutions, the smallest $A$ corresponds to $(x,y)=(600,60)$ which gives $A=36000$

Now $36000=2^5\cdot3^2\cdot 5^3$ and it is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) that there are $(5+1)(2+1)(3+1)=72$ factors.

Comment: You should say how you found the (smallest) solution - not pull it out of a hat like magic (that's where all the nontrivial work is).

Comment: No magic hat but easy but tedious work with the prime factors in play. Are there some magical hat that could be used?

Comment: @J.W. Tanner: Thanks for the edition but it is not  the numbers prime with the 36000 but the number of all its factors.

Comment: I was merely correcting spelling (there’s no “e” in “factors”)

Comment: Your link goes to the totient function. Anyway, thanks you very much.